# MVC Remote Attribute Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, remote-validation

I setup a remote validator in MVC to be sure that a company doesn't already exist when creating or editing a company on my page. Here is the model:

```
public class AdminCompany
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required")]
    [Remote("DoesCompanyExist", "Ajax", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage="This company already exists.")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string PortalsString { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the `DoesCompanyExist` function:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxOnly]
public JsonResult DoesCompanyExist(string CompanyName)
{
    var companies = new Companys();
    companies.GetBySqlStatement("SELECT CompanyName FROM Company WHERE CompanyName='{0}'", CompanyName);

    return Json(companies.Count == 0);
}
```

Everything is working just fine except for one issue. On my edit page, if the user goes into a company's edit page, then just saves it without changing anything, my remote validator is triggering a validation error. The reason is because the company does, in fact, already exist in the database, however, my remote validator doesn't realize that its the same record being modified.

Is there some kind of work around to this? Ideally, it would be nice if I could somehow pass the CompanyId onto my remote validator. That way I could exclude that ID from my `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`AdditionalFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.additionalfields%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) parameter for `RemoteAttribute`. This will allow you to, as you described, supply another field value (such as an entity ID) that can be used to validate edits (versus creates).

Comment: I'm trying this, but its returning null for some reason.

Comment: You may need to apply `BindAttribute`, and make sure you're including it in the edit action (as a hidden field perhaps-- `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CompanyId)`

Comment: I'm including it in my model. Would I still need to use `BindAttribute` and `Html.HiddenFor`?

Comment: I got it. I  didn't need `Bind`, but I did need to add it as a hidden field. Thanks @BradChristie

Comment: Not a problem.  And bone is only necessary if it had trouble mapping. The field does, however, need to be present, and a hidden field is most likely method.